# Include several references on the second level

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Assume we have this model :

```
public class Tiers
{
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Tiers Tiers { get; set; }
    public Titre Titre { get; set; }
    public TypeContact TypeContact { get; set; }
    public Langue Langue { get; set; }
    public Fonction Fonction { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
    public StatutMail StatutMail { get; set; }
}
```

With EF7 I would like to retrieve all data from the Tiers table, with data from the Contact table, from the Titre table, from the TypeContact table and so on ... with one single instruction. With Include/ThenInclude API I can write something like this :

```
_dbSet
     .Include(tiers => tiers.Contacts)
          .ThenInclude(contact => contact.Titre)
     .ToList();
```

But after Titre property, I can't include others references like TypeContact, Langue, Fonction ... Include method suggests a Tiers objects, and ThenInclude suggests a Titre object, but not a Contact object. How can I include all references from my list of Contact? Can we achieve this with one single instruction?

Answer (score 305, accepted):

`.ThenInclude()` will chain off of either the last `.ThenInclude()` or the last `.Include()` (whichever is more recent) to pull in multiple levels. To include multiple siblings at the same level, just use another `.Include()` chain. Formatting the code right can drastically improve readability.

```cs
_dbSet
    .Include(tiers => tiers.Contacts).ThenInclude(contact => contact.Titre)
    .Include(tiers => tiers.Contacts).ThenInclude(contact => contact.TypeContact)
    .Include(tiers => tiers.Contacts).ThenInclude(contact => contact.Langue);
    // etc.
```

Comment: BTW, this question inspired me to create issue [#2124](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2124)

Comment: why not:
`var contacts = _dbSet.Include(tiers => tiers.Contacts);`
`contacts.ThenInclude(contact => contact.Titre);`
`contacts.ThenInclude(contact => contact.TypeContact);`
`contacts.ThenInclude(contact => contact.Langue);`

Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @Doug No, you'd be creating new `Queryable` objects each time and never evaluating them. `contacts` would only ever have the original value you assigned to it.

Comment: what if `tiers.Contacts` is a `List<T>`? how would you specify item then?

Comment: This solution works but the resulting SQL statement results in three LEFT JOINs with Contacts (at least in my experience).  That is terribly inefficient.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: For new seekers: in 2020, with EF Core 3.1, my test with the accepted solution worked fine and it did not resulted in 3 left joins.

Comment: @heringer In 2021, with EF Core 5, I have tested this solution and it is perfect.

Comment: as .Include(tiers => tiers.Contacts) is repeated 3 times. Will it impact on performance?

Comment: @SriniV The C# compiler builds an Expression object for the query. EF then translates that expression to SQL and caches the result. So no, repeating that method call won't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 32):

For completeness' sake:

It is also possible to include nested properties directly via `Include` **in case they are not collection properties** like so:

```
_dbSet
    .Include(tier => tier.Contact.Titre)
    .Include(tier => tier.Contact.TypeContact)
    .Include(tier => tier.Contact.Langue);
```