# Including multiple children of child table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following database query using Entity Framework.

```
var results = await DbContext.TransloadingDetails
                    .Include(td => td.PurchaseOrder).ThenInclude(po => po.Customer)
                    .Include(td => td.PurchaseOrder).ThenInclude(po => po.Location);
```

I was just curious about the ramifications of include `PurchaseOrder` twice like this. I see no way to express this without including it twice. Is the duplicate safely ignored?

Comment: Yep, EF will interpret it the way you want.  That syntax is required to include multiple various children [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506692/efcore-linq-theninclude-two-foreign-keys-to-same-table)

Comment: There are no ramifications, EF works it all out. This is just how you can leverage the Linq methods to include multiple children without resorting to magic strings like `.Include(td=> td.PurchaseOrder).Include("PurchaseOrder.Customer").Include("PurchaseOrder.Location")`

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072360/include-several-references-on-the-second-level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from [EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#including-multiple-levels):

You may want to include multiple related entities for one of the entities that is being included. For example, when querying `Blogs`, you include `Posts` and then want to include both the `Author` and `Tags` of the `Posts`. To include both, you need to specify each include path starting at the root. For example, `Blog -> Posts -> Author` and `Blog -> Posts -> Tags`. It doesn't mean you'll get redundant joins; in most cases, EF will combine the joins when generating SQL.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Tags)
        .ToList();
}
```

You can also load multiple navigations using a single `Include` method. This is possible for navigation "chains" that are all references, or when they end with a single collection.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Owner.AuthoredPosts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Blog.Owner.Photo)
        .ToList();
}
```