# Linq Include child properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following tables: Persons, ContactsRelations, Contacts, Roles and Companies

So one Person has a list of contacts. Each contact has one property Role and one Company.

I want to retrieve a Person and for each contact retrieve also the properties Role and Company.

```
 query = db.Persons.Include(entity => entity.ContactRelations)
                .ThenInclude(relation => relation.Contact)
                .ThenInclude(contact => contact.Role);
```

With above linq I can get the person and the contact with the Role property filled. But Company property is empty.

I don't know how to fill the Company property and Role property at the same time.

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include several references on the second level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072360/include-several-references-on-the-second-level)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to duplicate the path from the last include (the only one in your case). Should look like this:

```
query = db.Persons
    .Include(entity => entity.ContactRelations)
       .ThenInclude(relation => relation.Contact)
           .ThenInclude(contact => contact.Role)
    .Include(entity => entity.ContactRelations)
        .ThenInclude(relation => relation.Contact)
            .ThenInclude(contact => contact.Company);
```